React native (Android) screen auto scaling with changing in global zoom
Getting scaling problem in react native , after changing the global scaling the app screen changes .
Normal Display - 
Scaled Display - 
Setting which i changed - 
Index.js -

import { AppRegistry, Text, LogBox, TextInput, NativeModules, Platform } from 'react-native';
import { PermissionNotification, getFCMToken } from './notification/permission';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import App from './App';
PermissionNotification();
getFCMToken();
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['new NativeEventEmitter']);
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();
Text.defaultProps = Text.defaultProps || {};
Text.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
TextInput.defaultProps = TextInput.defaultProps || {};
TextInput.defaultProps.allowFontScaling = false;
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
   NativeModules.CustomScaling.updateDisplayMetrics();
   NativeModules.CustomScaling.setDisplayScale();
   NativeModules.CustomScaling.disableAutoZoom();
   NativeModules.CustomScaling.disableZoom();
   NativeModules.CustomScaling.disableZoomDiable();
   NativeModules.CustomScaling.attachBaseContext();
}
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);


I tried making a custom  function and import it in my react native app , but it didn't help
@ReactMethod
    public void setDisplayScale() {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) reactContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        // metrics.scaledDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEVICE_STABLE;
        Set the desired density value.
        metrics.scaledDensity = 1.0f;
        metrics.density = 1.0f;
        Configuration configuration = reactContext.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.densityDpi = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEVICE_STABLE; // DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
        reactContext.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
    }

